# Bring to front user control - Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an user control called MovieDetails, I dragged it to the main form but when I write `MovieDetail.BringDetails();` ,  I get this error:

> 'MovieDetails' does not contain a definition for 'BringTofront'.

How can I access the BringToFront method ?

Comment: Every class that derives from the System.Windows.Forms.Control class has the BringToFront() method...

Comment: @Ionuț Gabriel Pițigoi  What is this `MovieDetail.BringDetails()` method? Does your usercontrol class inherit `UserControl` (ie. `MovieDetails: UserControl`)? Is it "hand-made"? (...)?

Answer (score 0):

Use instance. Add this to your user control.

```
private static UserControlName _instance;
public static UserControlName Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (_instance == null)
            _instance = new UserControlName();
        return _instance;
    }
}
```

Then, add the user control to your form.

```
this.Controls.Add(UserControlName.Instance);
//I prefer to use a panel then load the user controls on the panel so I don't have to set the location of the usercontrol
```

To call the `BringToFront()` and `SendToBack()` method,

```
UserControlName.Instance.BringToFront();
UserControlName.Instance.SendToBack();
```